# What is the purpose of FOUR RaspberryPI icons on boot?

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, boot

I get four RaspberryPi icons in upper left corner of the monitor screen at boot time.
**Does it have a purpose?
If so , why four?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Rpi logo used with the default kernel replaces the normal Linux penguin(s).

[image]

These indicate the number of processor cores detected by the kernel, hence on a Pi 2 or 3 there are 4.